# Nonconstant harmonic function that is constant on open subset

Tags: complex-analysis

The following question arose while I was doing some homework - it's not a homework problem, just a question that might allow me to generalize the homework problem:

Let $h$ be a (real-valued) nonconstant harmonic function on an open connected set $U$. Is it possible that for some nonempty open subset of $U$ that $h$ is constant?

Comment: I think this would imply that the solution is constant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91436/unique-continuation-principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reference:** Theorems 1.27 and 1.28 (page 21) of *Harmonic Function Theory* by Sheldon Axler, Paul Bourdon, and Wade Ramsay.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the reference.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you.

Answer (score -2):

No, by the isolated zeroes theorem.

Comment: Harmonic functions never have isolated zeros?

Comment: The isolated zeros theorem that I think you refer to only applies to holomorphic functions.